Julia err command fails?
I am not even sure what I did to get this error. Probably updated some packages/messed with environments for python?
Opened Julia and realized no packages were installed.
As I try to reinstall things, it fails to build Makie and also sometimes gives this error, when I try to run julia> err`
I am on arch linux.
(@v1.11) pkg> ┌ Error: curl_multi_assign: 1
└ @ Downloads.Curl /usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.11/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:57
┌ Error: curl_multi_assign: 1
└ @ Downloads.Curl /usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.11/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:57
┌ Error: curl_multi_assign: 1
└ @ Downloads.Curl /usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.11/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:57
┌ Error: curl_multi_assign: 1
└ @ Downloads.Curl /usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.11/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:57

[4095] signal 6 (-6): Aborted
in expression starting at none:0
unknown function (ip: 0x7f9acf93a3f4)
gsignal at /usr/bin/../lib/libc.so.6 (unknown line)
abort at /usr/bin/../lib/libc.so.6 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x7f9acee23f1f)
unknown function (ip: 0x7f9acef3fa7d)
uv_run at /usr/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia-internal.so.1.11 (unknown line)
ijl_process_events at /usr/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia-internal.so.1.11 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x7f9ab60db78e)
unknown function (ip: 0x7f9ab5c8bbbf)
wait at ./condition.jl:125 [inlined]
_wait at /build/julia/src/julia-1.11.1/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.11/FileWatching/src/FileWatching.jl:572
wait at /build/julia/src/julia-1.11.1/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.11/FileWatching/src/FileWatching.jl:600
#58 at /build/julia/src/julia-1.11.1/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.11/Downloads/src/Curl/Multi.jl:188
unknown function (ip: 0x7f9abe6807d3)
unknown function (ip: 0x7f9acee6683e)
Allocations: 18680311 (Pool: 18677468; Big: 2843); GC: 34
Aborted (core dumped)



How did you install Julia 1.11? Although your error messages are pretty random it might point at an installation from a unix package manager (probably pacman), which seems to be broken with some distributions, see https://julialang.org/downloads/ which specifically says Please do not use the version of "Julia" shipped by unix package managers.
